# Analytic function on a domain

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z) + \sin(z)$ is an analytic function on a domain D and $f(z) + \cos(z)$ is analytic on D, then $f(z)$ is constant on D. Is this true?

Comment: let take $f(z)=3$   ,then does both  $3+sin(z)$ and $3+cos(z)$    are  analytic or continuous?

Comment: Take a boringly simple example to contradict that: $\;f(z)=z\;$ , on any domain.

Answer (score 6):

Why would this be true? Since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are both analytic functions, if you take any analytic function $f$, the functions $f+\sin$ and $f+\cos$ will both be analytic.